# Intersection with plane

Tags: calculus, geometry

We have a function $f:\mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}$. Why in order to find the intersection with the plane $z=0$ do we define $S_{z=0}=\{ (x,y,z,t)| z=0 \}$ and then find $S_{z=0} \cap \text{ graph of f}$? i.e. why do we introduce a new variable?

Comment: According to my textbook: The graph of a function is determined with the method of intersections. With the term intersection of the graph $f$  we mean the intersection of the graph with a (vertical ) plane. @mvw

Comment: What does the $M$ that you defined represent? @mvw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The graph $G_f$ of $f$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}^3 \times \mathbb{R} = \{ ((x,y,z), t) \mid (x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3, t \in \mathbb{R} \}$, which we can embed in $\mathbb{R}^4$ by mapping $((x,y,z),t)$ to $(x,y,z,t)$.

A plane $z = 0$ in $\mathbb{R}^4$ looks like your $S_{z=0}$. And thus $S_{z=0} \cap G_f$ is the intersection.

Comment: We couldn't we pick for example $S_{z=0}=\{ (x,y,z)|z=0 \}$ ?

Comment: The graph consists of the pairs of arguments and function values, so it has one dimension more than the argument space. There the plane has to be defined. That last $S_{z=0}$ would be a plane in $\mathbb{R}^3$ only.

Comment: So with $t$ we represent $f(x,y,z)$ ?

Comment: Yes, it takes the function values $t = f(u), u = (x,y,z)$. Maybe it is easier to think about a function $g : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ first.

Comment: If we have a function with two variables, for example  $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}, (x,y) \mapsto |y|$, then is the intersection of the graph with the plane $xz$ that is defined by $y=0$ the following?

$$\{ (x,y,t)| t=0, y=0\}$$

Comment: $G_f = \{ (x, y, \lvert y \rvert ) \mid x,y  \in \mathbb{R} \}$. The plane is $E = \{ (x,0,z) \mid x,z \in \mathbb{R} \}$ and $G_f \cap E = \{ (x, 0, 0) \mid x \in \mathbb{R}\}$. This is what you got.